# Problem in rendering chart in BIRT when adding dynamic series with scripted data source

Tags: birt

I am creating a BIRT report which will contain chart which has been bound to a Scripted Data Source. I need to add series to this Bar chart on user request and hence I started following the below example.
http://birtworld.blogspot.com/2008/10/dynamically-adding-series-to-birt-chart.html

First I tried to run the exact same report(in the above page) in my deployment environment and it ran perfectly. Then I kept the main logic intact and replaced the Sample database with a custom Data Source. When I try to run this report in the same way, all I end up having is a blank page with no chart rendered.

I tried to put in logs at the appropriate places and found out that my datasource has been called and the collection has been initialized and is being returned to the BIRT report. But the part where the chart should have (in my opinion) filled the DataSet (which is connected to the chart) was not called.
Can anybody please point out as to where am I going wrong.

For the related attachments, Please have a look at http://www.birt-exchange.org/org/forum/index.php/topic/21486-problem-in-rendering-chart-when-adding-dynamic-series-with-scripted-data-source/

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I can't have access to the links you're refferring to.

However, the lack of results in your reports is generally caused by the lack of data to use.

Since you changed the data source, are you sure that the datasets are still fetching the same information? (are the output columns the same as with the example for each dataset?)

- If it's not the case, you will have to either modify the aliases of your output columns in order to match the ones used in the example.
- Or, you'll have to adapt every rendered object (remove every entry and refresh the data binding of every object, and update the values you're using as well).

Hoping this will help.